# Let $i:Y\to X$ be a closed immersion, then why is $i_*\mathcal{N}_{Y/X}\cong\mathcal{O}_X(Y)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to understand the equivalence of two different definitions of the adjunction formula, given smooth projective varieties $Y$, $X$ over $k$, with $i:Y\to X$ a closed immersion of codimension $1$.

Now, on the one hand, I have many sources which say that the adjunction formula tells us that $$\omega_Y=(\omega_X\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\mathcal{O}_X(Y))\vert_Y$$ while other sources, such as Hartshorne, say that the adjunction formla is $$\omega_Y = \omega_X\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\mathcal{N}_{Y/X}$$ though I don't fully understand in what sense the tensor product is being taken here. But why are these two formulae equivalent?

Comment: Dear @Monstrous Moonshine most people do not use $i_*$ unless there is cause for confusion. Are you wondering why $\mathcal{O}_X(Y)_{|Y}=\mathcal{N}_{Y/X}$?

Comment: Yes, I am wondering that.

Comment: What is your definition of the normal bundle?

Comment: I use the definition $\mathcal{N}_{Y/X} = i^*(\mathscr{I}_Y/\mathscr{I}_Y^2)'$.

Comment: Then what is your problem? $\mathcal{I}_Y=\mathcal{O}_X(-Y)$. $\mathcal{I}_Y/\mathcal{I}_Y^2=\mathcal{I}_Y\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\mathcal{O}_Y=\mathcal{O}_X(-Y)_{|Y}$.